# Joining an average rating to the end of all rows of a MySQL select

Tags: mysql, select, join, average, rating

For every `bd_comments.commentid` ( meaning unique comment ) I need to join an average of all the ratings other users have supplied to the end of the row of each comment.

The table commentrate holds all the rates each user makes and the common key is the `comment_id`. In comment rate the field is called `comment_id` and in `bd_comments` it is just called `commentid`.

I can make sql select the average and join it to a single row but I cannot make it do this for all the rows. The example below only returns one result where the comment_id is specified.

```
select commentrate.comment_id, floor(avg(commentrate.rating)), 
bd_comments.comment, bd_comments.author_id from commentrate, bd_comments 
WHERE commentrate.comment_id= 1
```

This statement selects average of all the ratings for a specific `commentid` and return the average attached to the other fields I need, but only returns one row. There are several unique `commentid`'s. I need a table that has a comments average rating on the end of the comment's row to make a top rated page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema(I guessed because you failed to provide one)

```
CREATE TABLE bd_comments 
    (
     commentid int , 
     comment varchar(10),
     author_id int
    );

CREATE TABLE commentrate 
    (
     comment_id int , 
     rating int,
     author_id int
    );

INSERT INTO bd_comments
VALUES
(1, "comment 1", 100),
(2, "comment 2", 200),
(3, "comment 3", 300);

INSERT INTO commentrate
VALUES
(1, 3.5, 100),
(2, 4, 100),
(3, 5, 100),
(1, 2.5, 200),
(2, 1, 200);
```

Here is the query

```
SELECT cr.comment_id, floor(avg(cr.rating)) rating,c.comment, c.author_id
FROM commentrate cr, bd_comments c
WHERE cr.comment_id = c.commentid
GROUP BY cr.comment_id
```

Output

```
| COMMENT_ID | RATING |   COMMENT | AUTHOR_ID |
|------------|--------|-----------|-----------|
|          1 |      3 | comment 1 |       100 |
|          2 |      2 | comment 2 |       200 |
|          3 |      5 | comment 3 |       300 |
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2aa36/1)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you again so much for your help!